# Open http url connection on starup and write parameter/value later in Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I am want to use java.net api to open a url and get response. This url going to hit millions of time per day to the same source with different parameter every time. This has to be very quick because number of tps is very high. I was wondering if it is possible to open connection once on start-up and writing param values later on each new hit.

I was hoping to do this way..

```
HttpURLConnection connection=null;
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
                       Url url1 = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9081/charging");
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long stop=0;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
             connection.setDoInput(true);
             connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
             connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
}
```

and passing this connection object to method.

```
public String openCharging(HttpURLConnection connection, ParamBean bean)
{
String response=null;
  String paramstring="ChargingMode="+bean.getMode+"&ChargingAmount="+bean.getEUP+.;.and so on
  BufferedReader in=null;
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
    wr.writeBytes(paramstring);
    wr.flush();
    try 
    {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                if(in!=null)
                {
                    response = in.readLine();
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {}finally{//close all except connection object}         
}
```

This need to be low latent as possible, but my knowledge on high performance java is limited.
Any help would be appreciated.

//Any other better solution is also welcome + apache alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't.

However you seem to be unaware that `HttpURLConnection` does connection pooling behind the scenes, so as long as you don't call `disconnect(),` and use the URL frequently enough, the connection overhead is already amortized.